# Periodic boundary condition

Tags: differential-equations

I want to solve a PDE as:

$\frac{\partial u}{\partial t}=\frac{\partial u}{\partial x}$, with conditions:
$u(x,0)=sin(\pi cos(x))$ and $u(x+2\pi,t)=u(x,t)$. I have solved it by hand and obtained:
$u(x,t)=sin(\pi cos(x+t))$. I would like to solve it both numerically and analytically by Mathematica. I have written:

```
NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x], u[x, 0] == Sin[Pi Cos[x]], 
  u[x, t] == u[x + 2 Pi, t]}, u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}].
```

What's the problem?

Comment: You can get Mathematica to solve this analytically by evaluating `DSolve[{D[u[x, t], t] == D[u[x, t], x], u[x, 0] == Sin[\[Pi] Cos[x]]}, u, {x, t}]`, which gives `{{u -> Function[{x, t}, Sin[\[Pi] Cos[t + x]]]}}` in version 10.3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a simple mistake - getting the order of the `t` and `x` arguments mixed up in a couple of places, giving you the error

> NDSolve::conarg: The arguments should be ordered consistently.

But then you should also replace the equation `u[x, t] == u[x + 2 Pi, t]` with `u[t, 0] == u[t, 2 Pi]` and it works just fine

```
sol = NDSolve[{D[u[t, x], t] == D[u[t, x], x], 
    u[0, x] == Sin[Pi Cos[x]], u[t, 0] == u[t, 2 Pi]}, 
   u, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}][[1]]
```

[image]

And you can compare the numerical and analytic solutions

```
Grid[{{DensityPlot[u[t, x] /. sol, {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 400], 
   DensityPlot[Sin[π Cos[x + t]], {t, 0, 10}, {x, 0, 5}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, ImageSize -> 400]}}]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! What does [[1]] in your code?

Comment: The `NDSolve` returns a doubly nested list for some reason, `{{u -> ...}}` ans so when you type `u[3,3] /. sol` it returns `{0.125417}`, which seems ugly to me.  `[[1]]`selects the first element of the list, so if I include it int he definition of `sol` then `u[3, 3] /. sol` just returns `0.125417`.  The plotting seems to work just fine without it.